# Assets object created from static method

Tags: c#, oop, static-methods

currently I am trying to use an object created from static method but it does not happen. I believe I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Here is my code that I use to create the object, this code is in separate class let's say it's name is CrusadersFactory.cs:

```
//Method for creating crusader Nate
public static void CreateNate(string name, int level, int health, int damage)
{
    Nate NateDragon = new Nate(name, level, health, damage);
    //Print the info for the new object NateDragon
    Console.WriteLine(NateDragon.name + " " + NateDragon.level + " "  + NateDragon.health + " " + NateDragon.damage);
}
```

And here is how I am trying to use the object, this code is in Program.cs:

```
CrusadersFactory.CreateNate("Nate", 100, 200, 300); //This works in order to create Nate, but It gives error if i try Console.WriteLin(CrusadersFactory.NateDragon.name)
Console.WriteLine("Nate's health is {0}", CrusadersFactory.NateDragon.health);
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Your method doesn't return anything and `NateDragon` isn't stored anywhere - it simply cannot be accessed outside of `CreateNate`

Comment: "*but it does not happen.*" its not a technical description of a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are able to call this without compiler error:

```
CrusadersFactory.NateDragon.health
```

That means you did actually create a static `NateDragon` property in your `CrusadersFactory`. However, **you never assigned anything to this property**.

```
public static void CreateNate(string name, int level, int health, int damage)
{
    Nate NateDragon = new Nate(name, level, health, damage);
}
```

What you've done here is declared and assigned a **local variable**. This variable only exists in scope of the `CreateNate` method, it does not exist outside of it.

What you should have done instead is to assign your created object to the static property you want to store it in:

```
public static void CreateNate(string name, int level, int health, int damage)
{
    CrusadersFactory.NateDragon = new Nate(name, level, health, damage);
}
```

Since the `CreateNate` method is also part of the `CrusadersFactory`, you can shorten this to:

```
public static void CreateNate(string name, int level, int health, int damage)
{
    NateDragon = new Nate(name, level, health, damage);
}
```

---

Very simply put, when you used `Nate NateDragon = ...`, you declared a new variable, rather than accessing the static class property `NateDragon` that you had already declared in your `CrusadersFactory` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your method has the void return type (returns no value). You should change this to return the type `Nate`.

```
public static Nate CreateNate(string name, int level, int health, int damage)
{
    var nate = new Nate(name, level, health, damage);
    //Print the info for the new object NateDragon
    Console.WriteLine(nate.name + " " + nate.level + " "  +  nate.health + " " + nate.damage);
    return nate;
}
```

Your usage example can then become:

```
var nate = CrusadersFactory.CreateNate("Nate", 100, 200, 300);
Console.WriteLine("Nate's health is {0}", nate.health);
```

Comment: Looking at OP's intended usage example, he's not trying to _return_ an object but rather _assign_ an object to a static property.

Comment: @Flater Sure, but I agree Owen that he should actually return it. Having a factory **not** returningn a new instance contradicts my understanding of a factory. Instead of answering the question being posted its often better to answer the actual problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I agree that returning a value is the usual factory approach, but I don't think that choosing to instead store it in the factory particularly removes the "factory purpose" of the class.

Comment: Thank you all guys, you all helped me to learn new things, Owen and Flater you guys are top!